# Understanding Linked Lists in Java

Tags: linked-list

[image]

Using the following list above, I'm attempting to determine the value of the following expressions below. This topic is relatively new in my course. (I'll highlight my answers in bold for you to see what I have tried.)

1. temp : **[7]]**
2. temp.value : **7**
3. temp.next.value : **3**
4. head.next : **[5]]**
5. temp.next.next : **2**
6. temp.value.next : **?**
7. head.next.next.value : **7**
8. temp.next.next.next.value : **null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the notation for a *node* is to wrap its value in square brackets -- which you have done for some answers.

Here is your list with corrections and remarks:

| Expression | Your answer | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `temp` | [7]] |  |
| `temp.value` | 7 |  |
| `temp.next.value` | 3 |  |
| `head.next` | [5]] |  |
| `temp.next.next` | 2 | [2]] |
| `temp.value.next` | ? | error |
| `head.next.next.value` | 7 |  |
| `temp.next.next.next.value` | null | error |

So most of your answers are correct, but `temp.next.next` is a node, not an integer, so it is `[2]]` instead of 2.

As `temp.value` is an integer, `temp.value.next` is an invalid property reference, and will raise an exception.

As `temp.next.next.next` is `null` (marked with a cross in the picture), `temp.next.next.next.value` is also an invalid property reference, and will raise an exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I really appreciate it! :)